# Ffmpeg split video

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to split video file by duration (for example, if I have video file with duration of 30sec and I want to get 10 chunks: 3sec, 3sec etc.. and m3u8 playlist).

I have  my-video.mp4 (30 sec).
When I run this command:

```
ffmpeg -i my-video.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c copy -an -map 0 -muxdelay 0 -muxpreload 0 -output_ts_offset 0 -f segment -segment_time 3 -segment_wrap 1000 -segment_list_size 1 -segment_list my-video.m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live my-video-%03d.mp4
```

The first problem is:
I receive only 4  mp4 files:

```
my-video-000.mp4 (8sec)
my-video-001.mp4 (8sec)
my-video-002.mp4 (8sec)
my-video-003.mp4 (5sec)
```

The second problem is:
my-video.m3u8 playlist is created, but with last segment only:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXTINF:5.033333,
my-video-003.ts 
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

What's wrong with my command. I have tried a lot of different combinations (after reading http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment and similar questions/answers on stackoverflow, but didn't succeed)